# Is it possible to do create a border-bottom with 2 different colors and a space between them?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I've found out the way to create a border bottom with 2 different colors, but is it possible to have a space between the 2 different colors like the picture shown above?

Comment: Why not showing your code what you have done already?

Comment: This is just an image sent by my user, so I don't have the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to tweak the percentages to get the white gap exactly where you want it, but this should get you started.

```css
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      to right, 
      rgba(0, 83, 124,1) 0%,
      rgba(0, 83, 124,1) 80%,
      rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%,
      rgba(255,255,255,1) 82%,
      rgba(255, 63, 63,1) 82%,
      rgba(255, 63, 63,1) 100%
    ) bottom left no-repeat; 
    padding: 6px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
  background-size: 100% 6px;
  color: rgba(0, 83, 124,1);
}
```

```html
<a href="">CONTACT US</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Arial-Bold";
  src: url(https://www.cufonfonts.com/download/font/single/48880/arial);
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Arial-Bold";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1b478d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 74%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #1b478d;
}

h2::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 24%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #e69399;
}
```

```html
<h2>Contact Us</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Achieve That Using CSS's Border Color Property

```css
h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #1b478d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.txt1 {
  border-bottom: 5px solid  #1b478d;
  margin-right: 4px; /* Space You Want between the Word "Contact" and "Us" */
}

.txt2 {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #e69399;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <span class="txt1">Contact</span><span class="txt2">Us</span>
</h2>
```

The `margin-right` property in `.txt1` is being used for the space between the both word "Contact" and "Us"

Comment: If we want space in middle of a letter like "U" shown in this question img, I thinks @authentic-science answer will work.